# Event not Firing on First KeyPress

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to call a Sub from within the keyPress event in a textBox, the problem is that the Sub will not get called until the second keyPress, at that time the keyPress processes the first key entered, if a third keyPress is done the sub will process the second keyPress and so on...  Here is an image;

[image: Form KeyPress]

And here is my code;

```
Private nonNumberEntered As Boolean = False

Private Sub txtAmount_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtAmount.KeyPress
    'Only allowed characters
    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789."
    nonNumberEntered = False
    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
        If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
                ' Invalid Character, notify clear and return
                MsgBox("Numbers only", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                txtAmount.Text = ""
                txtAmount.Focus()
                nonNumberEntered = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'If shift key was pressed, it's not a number.
    If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Then
        nonNumberEntered = True
    End If
    'Call the function to create a text line out of the numbers
    'Regex to ensure the string contains numbers
    Dim re As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d")
    If re.IsMatch(txtAmount.Text) Then
        If nonNumberEntered = False Then
            Dim newNum = txtAmount.Text.Trim
            'If there are any leading weird . in the string
            newNum = newNum.TrimStart(".")
            Dim newStr As String
            'Build the array
            Dim newDec As String() = newNum.Split(New Char() {"."c})
            If newNum.Contains(".") Then
                newStr = NumberToText(newDec(0))
                lblResult.Text = newStr & " Dollars and " & newDec(1) & "/100 "
            Else
                newStr = NumberToText(newDec(0))
                lblResult.Text = newStr & " Dollars and 00/100 "
            End If

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Debug your code.  Set a breakpoint at the top of the event handler and then step through it, line by line.  At the first point that the actual behaviour diverges from your expectation, you have found the issue.  If that never happens then your expectations are the issue.

Comment: My guess would be that the `Text` of the control hasn't actually changed when the `KeyPress` event is raised but that is something that would be quite obvious if you debugged your code properly, which you should ALWAYS do BEFORE posting a question here.  In that case, you would need to either handle the `TextChanged` event in order to use the `Text` (there's no reason you can't handle both and do some work in each) or else construct the text to be used yourself rather than relying on the `Text`.  I'd suggest the former.

Comment: Well, before you chastise me, I did just that, I set a breakpoint on [If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then] and the returned value is a "1" if I enter 1.  I then put a breakpoint on [If re.IsMatch(txtAmount.Text) Then] and the returned value of txtAmount.Text is empty.  At the second keyPress, the value of Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) equals the second number pressed, but newNum = txtAmount.Text.Trim equals the first number entered.  So telling me that "debugging" my code would help, (other than going line by line) is not much help.

Comment: Oh, and if I set a breakpoint on [Private Sub txtAmount_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtAmount.KeyPress], after the first number entered the return value of "e" is "1", but the txtAmount is "".  Breakpoint on [If re.IsMatch(txtAmount.Text) Then] is empty.  At this point txtAmount should contain the entered number.

Comment: If I enter a second number "e" holds that number, but txtAmount now holds the first entered number.  e.KeyChar holds the second number.

Comment: If you hadn't debugged your code then telling you to debug is the most help you can get.  If you're going to post a question here then you need to provide ALL the relevant information and you can't do that without debugging.  You need to tell us exactly where and how the execution of the code differs from your expectation and also exactly what data is in use at the time.

Comment: Then it's exactly as I have already described, so you already have the solution.  The `KeyPress` event can be used to prevent characters being entered into a control so it stands to reason that the event is raised before those characters have been entered.  Exactly as I said in an earlier comment, the `Text` property has not changed when the `KeyPress` event is raised so getting the value of the `Text` property will not get you the "new" text.  If you want the value of the `Text` property after it has changed then you need to handle the `TextChanged` event, as I said earlier.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but how can I call the TextChanged event in the middle of a keyPress event?

Comment: You can't and you don't.  Events aren't called.  Methods are called.  Events are raised.  Events of a `TextBox` are raised by that `TextBox`, not by you.  You're looking at this the wrong way.  Why are you handling the `KeyPress` event in the first place?  So that you can perform validation.  That's what you do then: you perform validation in the `KeyPress` event handler.  If validation fails then you prevent that character being entered and the `Text` won't change.  That means that you can handle the `TextChanged` event and use the `Text` knowing that it passed validation.

Comment: If you need to know what the new text would be if the pressed key is allowed then it's up to you to create that yourself.  The `Text` property gives you the old text and the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties tell you where the new character will go and whether it will replace existing text.  A bit of string manipulation can give you the proposed new text and you can then validate that.

Comment: It's not the validation that is causing my issue, it's that the sub is not getting called upon each keyPress.  I want to call NumberToText() on every validated keyPress, but like I originally stated, it only gets called upon the second validated keyPress.  For example, if I enter "1" in the textbox, it gets validated as true and then I want to call the sub, but it does not.  If I then enter a "2", it gets validated as true, but at that time the sub will run and use the "1" only, the "2" is left hanging.  For some reason the sub is not getting called on every validated keyPress.

Answer (score 1):

As @jmcilhinney alluded in the comments, you are trying to do too much in the `KeyPress` event handler.  That handler should only be used to allow valid key presses and suppress invalid key presses.  Whenever a valid key press is made, it is allowed to go through and then the `TextChanged` event handler will be called.  Setting `e.Handled = True` will suppress the key press and the `TextChanged` event will not be called.

```
Private Sub txtAmount_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    'Only allowed characters
    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789."

    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
        If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
                ' Invalid Character, notify clear and return
                e.Handled = True    'Set to True to 'swallow' the keypress and prevent the TextChanged event from firing.
                MsgBox("Numbers only", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                txtAmount.Text = ""
                txtAmount.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtAmount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    lblResult.Text = NumberToText(txtAmount.Text)
End Sub

Public Function NumberToText(input As String) As String
    'Convert value of amount to words here
End Function
```

You may also wish to look into using a `MaskedTextBox` which will handle the validation automatically.

Comment: Thank you, the TextChanged event is what I needed, I am calling the sub inside it and all is working as desired.  I thought about using a MaskedTextBox, and even played with it, but didn't like the results since my string could be as many as 7 digits with or without a decimal point. Again, thank you for the solution.

Comment: @Mgfranz - One issue with this code is that it does not prevent the user from pasting in an invalid value.  You may wish to prevent that somehow.

Comment: ShortCutsEnabled is set to False, so no pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am using as my solution, might be a bit of a kluge but it works;

```
Private nonNumberEntered As Boolean = False
Private Sub txtAmount_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtAmount.KeyPress
    'Only allowed characters
    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789."

    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
        If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
                ' Invalid Character, notify clear and return
                nonNumberEntered = True    'Set to True to 'swallow' the keypress and prevent the TextChanged event from firing.
                MsgBox("Numbers only", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                txtAmount.Text = ""
                txtAmount.Focus()
                lblResult.Text = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'If shift key was pressed, it's not a number.
    If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Then
        nonNumberEntered = True
        txtAmount.Text = ""
        txtAmount.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub txtAmount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtAmount.TextChanged
    'Call the function to create a text line out of the numbers
    'Regex to ensure the string contains numbers
    Dim t As TextBox = sender
    Dim foo As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, foo) Then
        'data is good
        Dim re As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d")
        If re.IsMatch(txtAmount.Text) Then
            If nonNumberEntered = False Then
                Dim newNum = txtAmount.Text.Trim
                'If there are any leading weird . in the string
                newNum = newNum.TrimStart(".")
                Dim newStr As String
                'Build the array
                Dim newDec As String() = newNum.Split(New Char() {"."c})
                If newNum.Contains(".") Then
                    newStr = NumberToText(newDec(0))
                    lblResult.Text = newStr & " Dollars and " & newDec(1) & "/100 "
                Else
                    newStr = NumberToText(newDec(0))
                    lblResult.Text = newStr & " Dollars and 00/100 "
                End If

            End If
        End If
    Else
        'data is bad
        nonNumberEntered = False
        txtAmount.Text = ""
        txtAmount.Focus()
        lblResult.Text = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that in the textChanged I am checking to see if the value is actually a number, if ot, clear contents and keep going.  In textChanged I also allow a decimal point, but nothing else, and then I clear everything making the user start over.  Simple, yet effective......

Answer (score 0):

Ok Chris, you were close.  What I needed to do was set e.KeyChar = "" and then trap the  and  in KeyPress.  So here is my final solution that is working as intended.

```
Private Sub cbCheckAmount_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles cbCheckAmount.KeyPress
    'Only allowed characters
    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789."
    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
        If e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Return) Or e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Tab) Then
            If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Or e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Tab Then
                If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
                    ' Invalid Character, notify clear and return
                    nonNumberEntered = True    'Set to True to 'swallow' the keypress and prevent the TextChanged event from firing.
                    MsgBox("Numbers only", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                    cbCheckAmount.Text = ""
                    cbCheckAmount.Focus()
                    lblTotalText.Text = ""
                    e.KeyChar = ""
                    nonNumberEntered = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'If shift key was pressed, it's not a number.
    If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Then
        nonNumberEntered = True
        cbCheckAmount.Text = ""
        cbCheckAmount.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub cbCheckAmount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbCheckAmount.TextChanged
    'Call the function to create a text line out of the numbers
    'Regex to ensure the string contains numbers
    Dim t As ComboBox = sender
    Dim foo As Decimal
    If nonNumberEntered = False Then
        If Decimal.TryParse(cbCheckAmount.Text, foo) Then
            'data is good
            Dim re As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d")
            If re.IsMatch(cbCheckAmount.Text) Then
                If nonNumberEntered = False Then
                    Dim newNum = cbCheckAmount.Text.Trim
                    'If there are any leading weird . in the string
                    newNum = newNum.TrimStart(".")
                    Dim newStr As String
                    'Build the array
                    Dim newDec As String() = newNum.Split(New Char() {"."c})
                    If newNum.Contains(".") Then
                        newStr = NumberToText(newDec(0))
                        lblTotalText.Text = newStr & " Dollars and " & newDec(1) & "/100 "
                    Else
                        newStr = NumberToText(newDec(0))
                        lblTotalText.Text = newStr & " Dollars and 00/100 "
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        'data is bad
        nonNumberEntered = True
        cbCheckAmount.Text = ""
        'cbCheckAmount.Focus()
        'lblTotalText.Text = ""
    End If

End Sub
```